SQL group by month with conditions
I'm trying to get event count from the SQL Server database grouped by months but with a few conditions. I can't build a query that makes the result I'm hoping to get.
I want to get current year's events where startTime is less than or equal to end of the x month and endTime is greater than or equal to start of the x month.
The x character represents all of the possible months in a year.
Example:
Events in January: startTime <= 01.31.2024 23:59 AND endTime >= 01.01.2024 00.00
So if the event is long, it could be counted over several months.
Desired result:
January: 12
February: 19
March: 22
...
December: 7

SQL Server <> MySQL; please only tag the product you are really using.

Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results, and your attempt.

I've added a different duplicate target based on the (now) completely different question.

You may use the following logic:
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    -- less than 1st of next month
    startTime < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0) AND
    -- ge than 1st current month
    endTime >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0);


Why mm for DATEADD and m for DATEDIFF? Why not be unambiguous and use MONTH for both? Using different abbreviations in the same expression implies m and mm have different meanings. (Plus I'll always argue for using the full name, not the abbreviation, anyway; too many people get confused with m being months, and n being minutes, especially when in .Net's formatting tools and then it's M for Months and m for minutes).)

This query returns correctly this month's events but how can I get the whole year's events grouped by months? Like this: January: 16, February: 19, March: 23. The number is the count of events in the month.

@Zibal That requirement isn't in your current question above.

I was unclear, sorry. I edited the post.
